# Spatial localization of Littlewood--Paley decomposition. Proving the fractional Hardy inequality.

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, littlewood-paley-theory

**INTRODUCTION**. I am trying to understand the proof of the fractional Hardy inequality
$$\tag{1}
\left\lVert \frac{f(x)}{\lvert x \rvert^s}\right\rVert_{L^2_x(\mathbb R^d)}\le C_{s, d}\lVert f\rVert_{\dot{H}^s(\mathbb R^d)},$$
taken from Lemma A.2 of T.Tao "Nonlinear dispersive equations", CBMS.

The proof relies upon a Littlewood--Paley decomposition $f=\sum_N P_N f$, where $N$ ranges over dyadic integers and
$$
\widehat{P_N f}(\xi)=\left( \phi(\xi/N)-\phi(2\xi/N)\right)\hat{f}(\xi), $$
with $\phi$ being a smooth bump function that equals $1$ on the unit ball. The relevance of this decomposition to (1) lies in the formula
$$\tag{2}
\lVert f\rVert_{\dot{H}^s(\mathbb R^d)}^2=\sum_N N^{2s}\lVert P_N f\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb R^d)}^2.$$

Now,  Tao's proof runs across the following lines. First, he decomposes the spatial variable $x$. Precisely, he notes the following bound for the left-hand side of (1):
$$\int_{\mathbb R^d}\left\lvert \frac{f(x)}{\lvert x \rvert^s}\right\rvert^2 dx \lesssim \sum_R R^{-2s}\int_{\lvert x \rvert\le R} \lvert f(x)\rvert^2 dx, $$
where $R$ runs over dyadic integers. So far, so good.

---

**QUESTION**. At this point, Tao fixes $R$ and focuses on a single integral $\int_{\lvert x \rvert\le R} \lvert f(x)\rvert^2 dx$. He claims that
$$\tag{3}
\left(\int_{\lvert x \rvert\le R} \lvert f(x)\rvert^2 dx\right)^\frac12 \le \sum_N \left( \int_{\lvert x \rvert \le R} \lvert P_N f(x)\rvert^2 dx\right)^\frac12,$$
where $N$ runs over the dyadic integers. This should "follow from Littlewood--Paley decomposition and the triangle inequality". **How to prove (3)**?

I am a bit confused because this looks like a spatially localized version of the decomposition
$$
\lVert f\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb R^d)}^2\sim \sum_N \lVert P_N f\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb R^d)}^2.$$
Now, the latter is obvious. But how can you infer (3), where you integrate on $\lvert x\rvert\le R$? You are going to have all sorts of mixed terms $\int_{\lvert x \rvert \le R}P_{N_1}f \overline{P_{N_2} f} dx$. As $R\to \infty$, these vanish by essential disjointness of Fourier supports. But here $R$ is fixed.

Comment: You have $f$ equal to the series of the Palye-Littlewood projections (in the $L^2$ sense hence pointwise a.e) so the result follows by Fatou’s lemma and the triangle inequality for the $L^2(B_R)$-norm no?

Comment: ^pointwise along a subsequence of course, but this is enough

Comment: @peek-a-boo: yes, I see your point. I think that may work. If you answer with that I will upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to peek-a-boo in comments. The standard Littlewood--Paley entails
$$
\lvert f \rvert^2=\lim_{\lvert N_0\rvert \to \infty} \left\lvert \sum_{\lvert N\rvert \le \lvert N_0\rvert} P_N f\right\rvert^2, $$
where $N$ and $N_0$ run over the dyadic integers. So by Fatou's lemma, letting $B_R=\{x\in \mathbb R^d\ :\ \lvert x \rvert\le R\}$,
$$
\int_{B_R}\lvert f\rvert^2\le \liminf_{\lvert N_0\rvert \to \infty} \int_{B_R} \left\lvert \sum_{\lvert N\rvert\le \lvert N_0\rvert} P_N f\right\rvert^2=\int_{B_R} \left\lvert\sum_{N} P_N f\right\rvert^2,$$
and now (3) follows by taking the square root and applying the triangle inequality.